# Flickr photo search API with space in search string

Tags: search, api, flickr

I am trying to find a way to search photos using text parameter but with a space in the search string.

I want to search for 'Zera zera' which is scientific name of a butterfly and I want the search to be precisely both the words with a space between them rather than just a word Zera which could return me 1000s of photographs with people having zera as part of their names.

Is there any way to do this in Flickr API?

Comment: This is what I got on yws-flickr Yahoo group by Tristan Savatier

"Text search using double-quotes does not seem to work, as it will return images that just have the word "zera", not "zera zera".

If the images have the tag "zera zera", then a tag search for zerazera (without the space) will return them.

currently there does not seem to be any public photo with the tag "zera zera" (or zerazera) on flickr.

There are a few other "zera" insects, which i found with a text search for "zera insect" (without the double-quotes)."

Comment: Above soulution is certainly useful but does not really address the generic problem I have at hand. So I am still looking for exact solution(s).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying for "Zera zera" query for "Zera zera species" and see the results.

Comment: Thanks for the work around suggestion @T S Srinivasamurthy. I have already used that for the time being. But I am trying to look for a more generic solution.